# Create Pivot Table not working on new Excel version

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My macro is supposed to create a Pivot Table and add specific filters.
I used the macro recorder for this, it works on my computer but not on newer versions of excel. Heres my code:

```
Cells.Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "1!R1C1:R1048576C13", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Tabelle2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("Tabelle2").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("PlatzID/Gerät")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Tagabfluss"), "Anzahl von Tagabfluss", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Anzahl von Tagabfluss" _
    )
    .Caption = "Summe von Tagabfluss"
    .Function = xlSum
End With
```

I tried to change `Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14` to `Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15` and other numbers which are for other excel versions but none seem to work.

I am using Excel 2010 my coworkers are using Excel 2013.
The Debug function highlights:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "1!R1C1:R1048576C13", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Tabelle2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Rory. Invalid Procedure

Answer (score 0):

First off, you really shouldn't use entire columns for the source data for a pivot table. Second, breaking the code up into discrete sections will help you to narrow down whether the error is in creating the pivotcache, or the pivot table itself. I'd suggest using:

```
Dim pivotSheet As Worksheet
Set pivotSheet = Sheets.Add
With Sheets("1")
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:="'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
End With

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(3, 1), DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

With pt
    With .PivotFields("PlatzID/Gerät")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Tagabfluss"), "Summe von Tagabfluss", xlSum
End With
```

Comment: vba runtime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument this is the exact error i get. The debuged marked code is         Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:="'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    End With

Comment: In which version? That would only work in 2013 or later.

Comment: I am using 2010 its working for me, my coworker is using 2013 it needs to run on 2013.

Comment: You can't use `xlPivotTableVersion15` in 2010, but it will work in 2013. I'd suggest you stick with `xlPivotTableVersion14` which will work in either.

Comment: I made the convert the macro into an addin and install it to my and coworkers computer they then use it on autogenerated data sheets its working for me as an addin

Comment: What format are the workbooks they are using it on, and are you sure there's always a worksheet called "1" in every workbook?